# What does "Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details." mean?

Tags: flutter

I was running my flutter project randomly not after flutter clean and I got this error message:

```
Note: C:\Users\engra\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\device_apps-2.2.0\android\src\main\java\fr\g123k\deviceapps\DeviceAppsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\engra\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.2.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

this the first i see this error message knowing that my flutter app was working perfectly fine.

I didn't try anything yet, this is my first time seeing this error message.

Comment: I need an explanation for this error message.

Comment: It is not an error message, it is a warning. It informs you that the Java code you're compiling uses deprecated features (the first two) or an unchecked cast (the last one), and that you can use the `-Xlint:deprecation` and `-Xlint:unchecked` options to get more information.

Comment: is it solvable?

Comment: Again, these are warnings, not errors, there isn't really anything to "solve". You can remove the cause for the warning if these are your sources, but these seem to be in libraries, so they should be fixed there by the maintainers of those libraries.